# Last div goes to a new line with padding in percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html/css and I'm trying to do an adaptive header for the website. I'm using padding-right with 5% for divs, but las div always goes to a new line and the parent div don't want to expand. I want parent div expand depending on the text in child divs. Also when I'm using padding in px, all works properly, but it loses adaptive part.
What am I doing wrong?

With padding in percents
[image: With percents]

With padding in pixels
[image: With pixels]

HTML and CSS

```css
button{
    height:34px;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:none;
    background-color:#fc592d;
    color:#ffeded;
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(44, 62, 80); float: left;">
    <div style="width: 47.36%; height: auto; margin: auto;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; float: left; padding-bottom: 4%; padding-top: 4%;">
        <div style="display:inline-block; padding-right:5%;">
        <img src="images/icon1.png" alt="farkops">
        <a class="href" href="#">One thing</a>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block; padding-right:5%;">
        <img src="images/icon2.png" alt="pricep">
        <a class="href" href="#">Second</a>
        </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block; padding-right:5%;">
        <img class="href" src="images/icon3.png" alt="otzivi">
        <a  class="href" href="#">Three</a>
            </div>
                <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <img src="images/icon4.png" alt="works">
        <a class="href" href="#">Fourth thing</a>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; display: inline-block; margin-top: 1.24%; margin-left: 2%;">
        <div style="">
        <p style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 3vh;"><span>7 (905)</span> 639-29-03</p>
        </div>
        <div style="">
        <button>Call</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPD1:
When I add one new div, the previous one fits just right (the parent div expands as I want), but the new one goes to new line.
[image]

Comment: Why did you set your second div (2nd row in HTML) to 47.36%? Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: The most likely reason is that the padding in percents is giving a larger padding in total than your px values, and therefore your elements won't fit. Elements that don't fit side by side will be dropped to the next line. If you used an amount in px that is too large, the same would happen.